# перевод надписи google recapcha

Tags: php, yii, форма, google-recaptcha

На сайте(на *yii*) подключил капчу от *Google*. Надпись капчи: *I'm not a robot*. По дефолту на английском языке, так как я не указывал параметра `hl` в подключаемом скрипте `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` к *API*.

Можно ли переводить эту надпись: *I'm not a robot*  в зависимости от выбранного пользователем языка на сайте? В документации пишет, что если параметр `hl` не указан, то язык пользователя определяется автоматически.

Если автоматически определяет, то по какому языку, системы (компьютера), или языку в браузере?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Гугл советует сделать так https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization#i18n

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
   lang : 'ru',
};
</script>
```